# How to wait until a lock is released in another thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, reentrantlock

I am trying to figure out how can we correctly wait until a lock is released in another thread.

I think the code will explain better what do I mean:

```
myLock.lock();
sendSomewhereMyLock(myLock); //creates new threads inside
myLock.waitUntilReleasedByAnotherThread(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//do something after the lock is released
```

I thought that `tryLock(long time, TimeUnit unit)` is the method which I need, but Java docs says that the method will be executed immediately because the lock was acquired by current thread:

> If the lock is available this method returns immediately with the
>   value true. If the lock is not available then the current thread
>   becomes disabled for thread scheduling purposes and lies dormant until
>   one of three things happens:
>
> - The lock is acquired by the current thread; or
> - Some other thread interrupts the current thread, and interruption of lock acquisition is supported; or
> - The specified waiting time elapses

What should I use then?

Comment: Is this an XY problem (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)? What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html)

With that you can define a condition like `workCompleted` and have the initial thread check and wait on that condition.

```
final Condition workCompleted = myLock.newCondition();
//...
myLock.lock();
try {
  final OtherThread otherThread = startOtherThread(myLock, workCompleted);
  while (otherThread.completed() == false) {
    workCompleted.await();
  }
} finally {
  myLock.unlock();
}

// other thread
doTheWork();
this.completed = true;
theLock.lock();
try {
  workCompleted.signal();
} finally {
  theLock.unlock();
}
```

There are several of such conditions pre-made in the [concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html), some of them might match your requirements better than the simple example above.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), which is designed exactly for this purpose:

> A synchronization aid that allows one or more threads to wait until a set of operations being performed in other threads completes.

Example usage:

```
CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
new Thread(() -> {
    doSomething();
    latch.countDown(); // Reaches 0, latch is released
}).start();
latch.await(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```